# What is the benefit of returning object than primitive types?

Tags: swift

What is the benefit of using the second method since both can perform same operation correctly?

import UIKit

```
class MathOperation: NSObject
{
    var num: Double = 0
    func add(a:MathOperation)->Double
    {
      num = num + a.num
        let result = num
        return result
    }
    func add2(a:MathOperation)->MathOperation
    {
        let result = MathOperation()
        result.num = num + a.num
        return result
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose `add2` follows the "builder pattern" and allows for a "fluent interface" with method chaining:

```
let result = someInput.add(someThingElse).square().multiply(three)
```

But that `num` field should probably be a constant (`let`). Otherwise you cannot safely pass these `MathOperation` instances around (someone might change their value).

And `MathOperation` should contain more than just a single number, otherwise the class is a bit pointless and one could just use `Double` directly. I imagine it might remember the sequence of operations that constructed it, so that it could print a term like "(1+3)^2" to describe itself.